# CakePHP call function from component

Tags: cakephp, components

I got a componentfile in CakePHP called OverviewComponent.php

In that component i've got 2 functions (public function A and public function B)

I want to call public function A inside public function B

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

In public function B you should call function a like this:

```
$this->a();
```